# Having trouble with None as default parameter

Tags: python, parameters, default-parameters

I am trying to understand how `None` as the default parameter works. I have a function that has 4 parameters, first is non-default followed by 3 parameters that are set `=None`.

Function: `send(name, website=None, to_email=None, verbose=False)`

Calling the function: `response = send(name, to_email=email, verbose=True)`

My question is when calling the function if I remove the `"to_email="` and leave it as just `email`, an error occurs saying that `to_email` is `None`. Doesn't it know that email is passed for `to_email` parameter (as it's the second parameter I pass)? Why do I have to explicitly say `email_to=email` when the parameter `email_to=None`?

This is my code that works:

```
def send(name, website=None, to_email=None, verbose=False):
    assert to_email != None
    if website != None:
        msg = format_msg(my_name=name, my_website=website)
    else:
        msg = format_msg(my_name=name)
    if verbose:
        print(name, website, to_email)
    # send the message
    send_mail(text=msg, to_emails=[to_email], html=None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(sys.argv)
    name = "Unknown"
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        name = sys.argv[1]
    email = None
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        email = sys.argv[2]
    response = send(name, to_email=email, verbose=True)
    print(response)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unnamed arguments are assigned to parameters in the order that they appear in the function definition. So if you write

```
send(name, email, verbose=True)
```

the `email` argument is assigned to the `website` parameter, since that's the second parameter in the function definition. The `to_email` parameter gets its default value `None`.

If you want to skip any parameters, you have to use named arguments for the rest.

If you want to be able to call it the way you're trying, you need to reorder the parameters:

```
def send(name, to_email=None, website=None, verbose=False):
```

Now `to_email` is the second parameter.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, thank you very much!